# What determines the order directory entries are returned by getdents?

Tags: linux, system-calls

Background is I have an existing application which lists directory entries; strace reveals it just calls getdents and lists them in the order returned. I would like them displayed in the same order as a call to ls with no arguments. Is it possible to update the directory data in some way to achieve this?

FS is ext4, if that makes any difference.

Comment: The fact that it is ext4 sure makes a difference. For vfat you could just move the directory to another filesystem, then copy the files back in the right order. I do it all the time for portable mp3 players. BTW, shell glob also sorts like `ls`. So - `cp -r music /media/my_player` will give me the wrong order, but `mkdir /media/my_player/music; cp -v music/* /media/my_player/music` - copies the files correctly! But this trick doesn't help on ext4! (maybe it has hashtable directories or something...)

Comment: Well, I found the same conclusion here: http://superuser.com/a/373621/269542 - so you can only sort. If you have sources of said application, you could add the sorting there, instead of hacking with LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you **really** are determined to change this program's behaviour (of which I assume that you don't have the source code available), you can use [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) to hook the call to `opendir` and `readdir` and replace it with your own, sorting wrapper. An example how such a hook could look like is the following:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct __dirstream
{
  int __fd;
  char *__data;
  size_t __allocation;
  size_t __offset;
  size_t __size;
  struct dirent __entry;
};

typedef struct _dirent_list {
  struct dirent *value;
  struct _dirent_list *next;
} dirent_list;

typedef struct _my_DIR {
  struct __dirstream orig;
  dirent_list *first_entry;
  int first_readdir;
} my_DIR;

DIR *opendir(const char *name) {
  DIR *(*orig_opendir)(const char*) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "opendir");
  DIR *dir = orig_opendir(name);

  // save additional information along with the
  // original DIR structure
  my_DIR *my_dir = calloc(1, sizeof(*my_dir));
  my_dir->first_readdir = 1;
  memcpy(my_dir, dir, sizeof(*dir));
  return (DIR*)my_dir;
}

struct dirent *readdir(DIR *dir) {
  struct dirent *(*orig_readdir)(DIR*) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "readdir");
  my_DIR *my_dir = (my_DIR*)dir;
  dirent_list *item;

  if (my_dir->first_readdir) {
    struct dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = orig_readdir(dir))) {
      // exercise for the reader:
      // implement insertion sort here 
      item = calloc(1, sizeof(*item));
      item->value = entry;
      item->next = my_dir->first_entry;
      my_dir->first_entry = item;
    }
    my_dir->first_readdir = 0;
  }

  if (!my_dir->first_entry)
    return NULL;

  item = my_dir->first_entry;
  struct dirent *result = item->value;
  my_dir->first_entry = item->next;
  free(item);

  return result;
}
```

It overrides `opendir` and `readdir` to return the entries in reverse order (you can adapt this for sorting too). This is how you use it with a program `test` that simply lists the directory entries in the order they are received:

```
$ gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libhookdir.so hookdir.c -ldl
$ ./test
..
test
.
hookdir.c
libhookdir.so
test.c
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libhookdir.so ./test
test.c
libhookdir.so
hookdir.c
.
test
..
```

Hah! This works. We just hooked a libc function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I just achieved the same thing using code from here: [LD_PRELOAD library to speed directory traversal](http://www.redhat.com/archives/ext3-users/2008-May/msg00006.html). Looks like this will be a solution for now, though I'm still curious as to what algorithm the original getdents uses.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way you can manipulate the filesystem metadata to have `getdents(2)` return directory entires in the same order as the sort order that `ls(1)` applies to the directory entires.

You can always modify your program to sort entries using the same algorithms that `ls(1)` provides, though this requires at least O(N) memory and O(N Log N) time for sorting a directory with N entries. You'll have to decide if it is worth the implementation, memory, and time, to sort in the same manner as `ls(1)`.