# How are dirent entries ordered?

Tags: c, directory, dirent.h

I am at a loss as to how `dirent` entries are ordered. For example, if I had the code

```
DIR* dir = opendir("/some/directory");
struct dirent* entry;

while ((entry = readdir(dir))
    printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
```

This may output something like the following:

```
abcdef
example3
..
.
123456789
example2
example1
```

As you can see, this output is not alphabetically ordered. So, I was wondering how exactly `dirent` entries *are* ordered? What causes some entries to have a higher precedence than others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not ordered in any relevant way. It's up to the implementation to retrieve and return directory entries in whatever order is most convenient.

*Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment*, 3rd ed., goes a little further and even says that the order is usually not alphabetical (Chapter 4, Section 4.22):

> Note that the ordering of entries within the directory is
>   implementation dependent and is usually not alphabetical.

If you're wondering, the output of `ls` is sorted because `ls` sorts it.

Comment: Whether or not the ordering is "usually" alphabetical depends on the filesystem. Some filesystems store filenames in sorted order, causing the files to always be returned sorted.

Answer (score 3):

They are not ordered alphabetically; they are retrieved in the order that the filesystem maintains them.

The directory "file" simply contains a list of filenames and inode numbers.  For some filesystem types, the filesystem prefers to not split a filename/inode value across *blocks*. As the filesystem adds or removes files from the list, it may find space in one of the blocks.  Other schemes (such as frequently-used filenames being earlier in the list) are possible.

A list sorted by filename depends upon the way things are sorted: it can be locale-dependent.  (The filesystem does not know or care about your locale-settings). So that decision is left to applications rather than the filesystem itself.

For additional comments, see

- [What determines the order directory entries are returned by getdents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866577/what-determines-the-order-directory-entries-are-returned-by-getdents)
- [What is the “directory order” of files in a directory (used by `ls -U`)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-directory-order-of-files-in-a-directory-used-by-ls-u)
- [In Bash, are wildcard expansions guaranteed to be in order?](https://serverfault.com/questions/122737/in-bash-are-wildcard-expansions-guaranteed-to-be-in-order)